# Javascript match on third type of string

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract a version and need to match on a third variant [as shown here](https://regex101.com/r/cSOhsY/1):

```
ersion ([^,]*)(,)? RELEASE
```

Need to match on:

```
Version 03.06.07b.E, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Version 03.06.07b.E RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
version 1.3(2)ES3
```

Match fails on the third row.

Comment: How about `ersion (?:([^,]*)(,)? RELEASE|.*)`? Your question is i poor shape since it is not clear what is allowed/not allowed for the 3rd match. It is not well specified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Try [`/Version ([^,]*)(?:,? RELEASE)?/i`](https://regex101.com/r/rAnhMq/1), but it seems you do not even need `(?:,? RELEASE)?` if you want to extract just what `([^,]*)` captures. [`/Version\s+([^,\s]*)/i`](https://regex101.com/r/rAnhMq/2) might be all you need.

Comment: Also: "Version 03.06.07b.E RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1) RELEASE" will match your regex".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third string is not matched because it does not contain the required `RELEASE` substring.

It seems all you need to match is any 0+ chars other than whitespace before the `,` char and after `Version` substring.

Use

```
/Version\s+([^,\s]*)/i
(?i)Version\s+([^,\s]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rAnhMq/2).

The `Version` will match `version`, too, due to the case insensitive flag, `\s+` matches 1+ whitespaces and `([^,\s]*)` will capture 1 or more chars other than whitespace and `,`.